# Shipment tracking, returning date gives Run Time Error 424 Object Required

Tags: excel, vba, return, runtime-error

So I'm working on a project for a coworker and I've run into an issue. I've never worked with Excel VBA before and I have VERY little training in coding at all. StackOverflow and dozens of other websites have been a huge help. I'm just not sure where to go for this.

The goal.

- navigate to a webpage
- wait for page to load
- Return the delivery date back to excel (cell b1)

Here's my code so far

```
Public Function RoadRunnerTracking()
Dim IE1 As Object
Dim DeliveryCollection As Object
Dim ProUrl As String


Set IE1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

ProUrl = "https://www.rrts.com/Tools/Tracking/Pages/MultipleResults.aspx?PROS=" & Range("a1")

With IE1
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ProUrl
    Do Until Not IE1.Busy And IE1.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With

Set DeliveryCollection = Trim(IE1.document.getElementsByTagName("Span")(16).innerText) 'THIS LINE RETURNS A RUN TIME ERROR 424 OBJECT REQUIRED
Range("b1").Value = DeliveryCollection
Set IE1 = Nothing

End Function
```

This isn't a polished function yet I'm aware. I'm just trying to work out some kinks.

What I don't understand is that I tested that line in another function and it worked fine. I cheated on the test function pasting the link directly to the results page rather than running the tracking number, but I would think it would be the same.

Here is the code that the line seems to work in.

```
Public Function PartTwoTest()
Dim IE1 As Object

Set IE1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

With IE1
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://www.rrts.com/Tools/Tracking/Pages/MultipleResults.aspx?PROS=359607744"
    Do Until IE1.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
    Loop
End With

DeliveryCollection = Trim(IE1.document.getElementsByTagName("Span") (16).innerText)
Range("b1").Value = DeliveryCollection

Set IE1 = Nothing

End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be so much easier to just go directly to the tracking number page and construct the link like this: `https://www.rrts.com/Tools/Tracking/Pages/MultipleResults.aspx?PROS=123456789` where `123456789` is the assumed tracking number.

Comment: That is a great point. I didn't realized that he url was so simple. I'll definitely modify the code to reflect that. Unfortunately (while I haven't tried it yet) that wouldn't affect the run time error that's occurring would it? I'd imagine my code would be much more simple, but I'd still have the same problem.

Ultimately I'd also like to modify this to work for pilot and fedex and some other carriers as well. I'm not sure if their urls would be so simple, but that would work for this application at least.

Comment: Each website is different and therefore you cannot use one post to solve it all. Each post should be very specific to one particular problem. You might want to read up on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and possibly also take the tour to learn more about the specifics of this site: http://stackoverflow.com/tour Afterwards, you might want to revise your above post to reflect the new insights.

Comment: `Set DeliveryCollection = Trim(IE1.document.getElementsByTagName("Span")   (16).innerText)` -- this looks strange. You want the result of `Trim()` - that is a string - set as an object to `DeliveryCollection`. This cannot work, as only objects can be set as, well, an object. In the working version of the code, although `DeliveryCollection` is not declared, it gets a value assigned without `Set` (means: no objects). Have you tried in your code to simply remove the `Set`? For this to work you must also change `Dim DeliveryCollection As Object` to `Dim DeliveryCollection As String`

Comment: Leviathan - THAT WORKED THANK YOU. I really appreciate the help from both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think deliverycollection needs to be a string.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. That took care of it. Now to run into 100 more problems trying to get this to work as needed, haha. Hopefully anything that comes up I can sort out myself, but you and everyone else have been a huge help.